# Get the coordinates of a position on a 3dgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

I have a Firemonkey form with a 3dgrid component on form set to (0,0,0). I would like to get the coordinates of a spot on the grid when the mouse is clicked. I know how to get the screen position of the cursor, but I need the coordinates on the 3d grid itself relative to the mouse position on the 3dgrid.

Comment: Firemonkey in XE2 and XE3 are two separate things, and neither of them has to do with `object-pascal`. They're both specific to Delphi, which is *not* Object Pascal. You'll need to decide whether your question is about FM (XE2) or FM2 (XE3).

Comment: @ Kevin I am using the Delphi side of Rad Studio XE3, Isn't that Object-pascal? As opposed to C++

Comment: :-) My name is Ken, but the answer is: No, [they are not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15699788/62576).

Comment: @Ken* It's been a long day :)

Comment: No problem. No offense taken. You did see the smile, right? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try that ...

Emmanuel

```
procedure TFormMain.EveOnMyLayer3D_MouseUp(Sender: TObject;
      Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single; RayPos,
      RayDir: TVector3D);
var
  P3: TVector3D;
  LocalX, LocalY: single;


begin
  if MyLayer3D.RayCastIntersect(rayPos, rayDir, P3) then
  begin
    P3 :=  MyLayer3D.AbsoluteToLocalVector(P3);
    LocalX := P3.X*MyLayer3D.Resolution;
    LocalY := P3.Y*MyLayer3D.Resolution;
    ...
```